# How to calculate rolling average of same weekday as current row in Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery

Due to certain restrictions, I have to use legacy SQL.

Right now, I have this which is a rolling sum of last 21 days(corresponding to 3 weeks), but I am really looking for a way to do a rolling sum of 3 previous weekday corresponding to the same week day as the current row.

```
AVG(sales_total) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date RANGE BETWEEN 22 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS avg_of_last_3_week
```

EDIT:

Table A

```
+-------+---------+---------+-----------+
| id .  |  date   | weekday |sales_total|
+-------+---------+---------+-----------+
| 1     | 01-01-17|    1    |     5     |
| 2     | 01-02-17|    2    |     .     |
| 3     | 01-03-17|    3    |     .     |
| 1     | 01-08-17|    1    |     10    |
| 2     | 01-09-17|    2    |     .     |
| 3     | 01-10-17|    3    |     .     |
| 1     | 01-15-17|    1    |     15    |
| 2     | 01-16-17|    2    |     .     |
| 3     | 01-17-17|    3    |     .     |
+-------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

I would like the resulting query to return Table A with an extra column which is the rolling average (for example, the below row would be what I expect for id 1 on 01-22-17). The rolling average is only the average for the previous 3 sundays (5+10+15))

```
+-------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| id    |  date   | weekday |sales_total|rolling_avg|
+-------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 1     | 01-22-17|    1    |     15    |    10     |
```

Thank you

Comment: Provide simplify example of input and expected output so we can help you! Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL (and if you still bound to Legacy SQL - you can easily "translate below to Legacy)

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT id, sales_date, weekday, sales_total, 
  AVG(sales_total) OVER(rolling_3_previous_same_weekdays) rolling_avg
FROM (
  SELECT *, EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM sales_date) weekday
  FROM t
)
WINDOW rolling_3_previous_same_weekdays AS (
  PARTITION BY id, weekday 
  ORDER BY sales_date 
  ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  )
ORDER BY weekday, sales_date
```

you can test / play with it using dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1 AS sales_total, DATE '2017-01-01' sales_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,  2, DATE '2017-01-02' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,  3, DATE '2017-01-03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,  4, DATE '2017-01-04' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,  5, DATE '2017-01-05' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,  6, DATE '2017-01-06' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,  7, DATE '2017-01-07' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,  8, DATE '2017-01-08' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,  9, DATE '2017-01-09' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 10, DATE '2017-01-10' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 11, DATE '2017-01-11' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 12, DATE '2017-01-12' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 13, DATE '2017-01-13' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 14, DATE '2017-01-14' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 15, DATE '2017-01-15' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 16, DATE '2017-01-16' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 17, DATE '2017-01-17' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 18, DATE '2017-01-18' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 19, DATE '2017-01-19' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 20, DATE '2017-01-20' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 21, DATE '2017-01-21' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 22, DATE '2017-01-22' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 23, DATE '2017-01-23' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 24, DATE '2017-01-24' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 25, DATE '2017-01-25' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 26, DATE '2017-01-26' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 27, DATE '2017-01-27' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 28, DATE '2017-01-28' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 29, DATE '2017-01-29' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 30, DATE '2017-01-30' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 31, DATE '2017-01-31' 
)
SELECT id, sales_date, weekday, sales_total, 
  AVG(sales_total) OVER(rolling_3_previous_same_weekdays) rolling_avg
FROM (
  SELECT *, EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM sales_date) weekday
  FROM `project.dataset.your_table
)
WINDOW rolling_3_previous_same_weekdays AS (
  PARTITION BY id, weekday 
  ORDER BY sales_date 
  ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  )
ORDER BY weekday, sales_date
```

I hope as soon as you get an idea of above approach  - you can easily reproduce it with BigQuery Legacy SQL - the only function used here that specific to Standrad  SQL is EXTRACT() - but looks like you will not even need it as weekday already part of your data

Good luck! :o)

Comment: please consider voting up if answer helped!